# Disable changing of checkbox in listView android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

Is it possible to disable the user clicking a checkbox item in a listView in android? I have a listView where the programme decides what is checked and not checked and I dont want the user changing the state of the checkboxes. Is there an easy way to do this?

I have tried setting the setClickable to false but that didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use a `CheckBox` if you do not want the user to check and uncheck it. Use something else, such as icons, to indicate checked and unchecked state.

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to allow user to set the value for `checkbox`, then simply use this:
`checkbox.setenabled(false)` or equivalent thing in the `xml`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare's comment is of course correct - You should not use a checkbox if the user cant actually interact with it, that's confusing to your user.

However to directly answer your question is should just be a matter of using `checkbox.setEnabled(false)`. Of course you'll need to be doing this for every row.

The alternative is of course to use colour or icons to indicate your state. Background color would only require a correct color state list on the list view (`android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_state_drawable"`) and for an icon just override getView. Something roughly like the following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
    }
    MyItemType data = getItem(position);
    ImageView checkImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state_icon);
    checkImage.setImageResource( data.isSelected()? R.drawable.ic_selected : R.drawable.ic_not_selected ) {
    return convertView;
}
```